# If radial projection is bijective then is it a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Suppose $S$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ and $0\not\in S$. Now consider the radial projection $f: S\to\mathbb{S}^2$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{x}{||x||} \hspace{5mm}\mbox{ for all $x\in S$}$$ Now suppose $f$ is bijective, then does this imply that $f$ is a homeomorphism ? If not in general, is it true when $S$ is compact ?

Comment: If $S$ is compact, it is true. Exercise : every continuous bijective map from a compact space to a Haussdorf space is a homeomorphism on its image

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a homeomorphism $S$ must be compact, as $\mathbb{S}^2$ is. On the other hand, every bijective continuous map from a compact space onto a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, as Selim Ghazouani already said in his comment.

So we conclude: the bijective map $f$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $S$ is compact.

Comment: The intersting question raised up by this remark is to find out if there exists a non-compact surface $S$ admiting a continuous bijection from $S$ to $S^2$.

Comment: In the one-dimensional case we have a continuous bijection $f : [0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{S}^1, f(x) = (\cos(x),\sin(x))$ which is not a homeomorphism. Surely we can generalize this counterexample for higher-dimensional cases. In this case we could take $S = [0,2\pi) \times [0,2\pi) \times \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I don't think this approach would lead to a counter example.  The problem here is that you consider surfaces (or curves) with boundary, which seems proscribed. In that case I can prove there is no such counter-example in the one-dimensional case